# How to check all values in a column are lowercase?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to check if all values in column `A` are lowercase strings.

How would one go about this?

I also want to `assert` if there are any which are not lowercase.

Strings can be like `some_string` or `stringystring` etc.

Comment: `df['A'].str.lower().eq(df['A']).all()`?

Comment: or `df['A'].str.contains('[A-Z]').any()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
df['A'].str.islower().all()
```